# jQuery UI1.9.0 Accordion: how to activate on accordion with click in another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, triggers, accordion

I hope someone can help me: I have three accordions and what I wanna do is, that if e.g. the second point of accordion 1 is clicked and is opening, simultaneously point two of accordion 2 and 3 should open too. Same procedure when closing.

It also should work when I click one point of accordion two or three, that the other two accordions simultaneously do the same.

I was thinking of trigger(), but do not know what event to trigger there exactly.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `beforeActivate` event on the master accordion, and then set the `active` option on the other accordion. I couldn't find anywhere that the accordion exposes it's active panel number within the ui parameter directly, so I had to parse it from the id.

```
$("#two").on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
  var newPanelID = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
  var accordionActivePanel = parseInt(newPanelID.split("-").pop(), 10);
  $('#three').accordion("option", "active", accordionActivePanel);
});
```

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pnzla) shows three accordions. The first is independent. The second one controls the third, but the third one can be changed without affecting the other two.